# wget unable to locally verify the issuer's authority but curl works

Tags: wget, certificates, https

After updating from Ubuntu 16 to 18, wget stopped working (among other stuff), while curl works properly.

```
$ curl -v https://google.com
...
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google LLC; CN=*.google.com
*  start date: Jul 29 17:24:58 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 27 17:24:58 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "google.com" matched cert's "google.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=GTS CA 1O1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
...
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
$ wget https://google.com
--2019-08-18 20:31:03--  https://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 172.217.13.110, 2607:f8b0:4020:804::200e
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|172.217.13.110|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify google.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=GTS CA 1O1,O=Google Trust Services,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to google.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

**Edit**:

What I have tried so far:

- using `sudo wget https://google.com`
- run as root `sudo su; wget https://google.com`
- reinstalling `apt-get purge wget; apt-get install wget`

Answer (score 1):

it should be finding google's root certs. So something is asmiss
try:

sudo apt install ca-certificates

or

sudo apt reinstall ca-certificates

Some other are root certs are however not present by default (at least on my 20.04)

wget --ca-certificate=<ca-root.crt>   https://....

The root cert you can get from the cert vendors site

Comment: This fixed the issue for me on a brand-new install of Ubuntu 22.04